# How make input disable/enable with selecting option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make input enable when some option is selected from the drop-down

I wrote code for solving this problem, but it doesn't work.
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<select class="form-control" id="dropDown">
      <option id="n" value="0"> Тип N </option>
      <option id="p" value="1"> Тип P </option>
      <option id="c" value="2"> Тип C </option>
      <option id="v" value="3"> Тип V </option>
      <option id="t" value="4"> Тип T </option>
      <option id="s" value="5"> Тип S </option>
</select>

   <div>
      <label class="control-label">
          <span th:text="#{size}"></span>
      </label>
     <input id="size" type="text" class="form-control" />
   </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script th:inline="javascript">

  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
       if( $(this).val() === 1) {
           $('#size').props( 'disabled', false );
       } else {
            $('#size').props( 'disabled', true );

        }
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm expecting that when I select the option "Тип P" input (id="size") should be enabled, if other options selected it should stay disabled

Comment: There's no such method in jQuery as `.props()`. And you have `$('#dropdown')` but the ID is `dropDown` (note the case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`===` is strictly equality operator, it checks both *value* and *type*, and as the value of an  element is always a string, comparing it to a number will always fail.

**Please Note:** You also have typo in `props`, should be `prop`. The attribute *id* used in the control (`dropDown`) and code (`dropdown`) does not match with each other.

Change

```
if( $(this).val() === 1) {
```

To

```
if( $(this).val() === "1") {
```

Comment: he's also using `props` instead of `prop`

Answer (score 1):

You are making three mistakes:

- `this.val()` returns a string but you are comparing it with a number `1`.
- There is a little typo `$('#dropdown')` should be `$('#dropDown')`
- Secondly use `prop` instead of `props`

You are setting `true` and `false` so you can direclty pass the condition to `prop()`

```
$('#dropDown').change(function() {
     $('#size').prop( 'disabled', $(this).val() !== "1" )
});
```

```js
$('#dropDown').change(function() {
     $('#size').prop( 'disabled', $(this).val() !== "1" )
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<select class="form-control" id="dropDown">
      <option id="n" value="0"> Тип N </option>
      <option id="p" value="1"> Тип P </option>
      <option id="c" value="2"> Тип C </option>
      <option id="v" value="3"> Тип V </option>
      <option id="t" value="4"> Тип T </option>
      <option id="s" value="5"> Тип S </option>
</select>

   <div>
      <label class="control-label">
          <span th:text="#{size}"></span>
      </label>
     <input id="size" type="text" class="form-control" />
   </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script th:inline="javascript">


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can shorten your function by using ternary operators.